# How to rotate a translated texture around its center

Tags: opengl, glsl, 2d

I'm working on the following shader that

1. translates (on y)
2. rotates
3. repeats (tiles)

a texture:

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform vec2 resolution;

varying vec4 vertColor;
varying vec4 vertTexCoord;

uniform float rotation;
uniform float yTranslation;

void main() {
  vec2 repeat = vec2(2, 2);
  vec2 coord = vertTexCoord.st;

  coord.y += yTranslation;

  float sin_factor = sin(rotation);
  float cos_factor = cos(rotation);
  coord += vec2(0.5);
  coord = coord * mat2(cos_factor, sin_factor, -sin_factor, cos_factor) * 0.3;
  coord -= vec2(0.5);

  coord = vec2(mod(coord.x * repeat.x, 1.0f), mod(coord.y * repeat.y, 1.0f));

  gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, coord) * vertColor;
}
```

## Current behavior

[image: Current]

## Desired behavior

I want the texture to always rotate around the center, no matter how far it has been translated.

[image: Desired]

Simply swapping the order of the steps results in weird behavior. What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by the center of the texture? (0.5, 0.5)?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Is the question imprecise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem statement in the question is really wrong:  Your addtional comment (to a now deleted answer):

> I have a boat that always stays in the center of the screen, the water texture (controlled by this shader) under it moves to make it look like the boat is moving. The movement of the water texture is controlled by `rotation` (for steering) and `yTranslation` (for how far the boat has moved forwards/backwards)

makes it clear that you're asking for a different thing, and the approach described in the question is simply not going to solve your problem.

When your boat moves *and* rotates, it will basically travel on a *curve* (and you want the inverse of that curve to travel through texture space). But your 2dof parameters `rotation` and `yTranslation` are not capable of describing the curve. Your problem needs at least another parameter `xTranslation` - so in the end, you need a 2D vector describing the position of your boat + an angle describing the rotation. And you need to properly accumulate this data at each simulation step:

- update the `rotation` accordingly
- calculate the 2D vector your ship is heading tom as defined by the current `rotation`
- scale it according to the velocity of the movement
- accumulate it onto the `position` vector.

Then, your shader simply has to
  1. translate the texcoords by `position`  (or `-position`, whatever you store)
  2. Rotate around the pivot point (which is constant and only depends on how you layed out your texture space)

> ```
> coord = vec2(mod(coord.x * repeat.x, 1.0f), mod(coord.y * repeat.y, 1.0f));
> ```

that's a waste of GPU ALU cycles, the TMUs will already do the `mod` for you with the `GL_REPEAT` wrap modes.

However, what you now have here is rotation, scaling and translation: so just use *a single matrix* for the whole texcoord transformation - the accumulation of the 2D position that I talked about earlier can nicely by done with the matrix representations. It will also remove the `sin` and `cos` from your shader, which is another huge waste right now.